# Accessing fields in tuples

Tags: haskell

I'm teaching myself Haskell, and while it was a most enlightening experience so far, I find some things that are easily done in C family of languages still a mystery. So, here is my very basic problem. I want a function to extract the tuples with a certain field equal to a given value. So far I have this code

```
withJob :: [(String, String, String)] -> String -> [String]
withJob [] _ = []
withJob ((_,_,x):xs) job
| job == x = x:(withJob xs job)
| otherwise = (withJob xs job)

users :: [(String, String, String)]
users = [("Jack", "22", "Programmer"), ("Mary", "21", "Designer"), ("John", "24", "Designer")]
```

When called like this `users 'withJob' "Programmer"` it outputs `["Programmer"]` but I would like it to output `[("Jack", "22", "Programmer")]`, however I don't know how to access the tuples and not the job(`x`) in `job == x = x:(withJob xs job)`

Comment: Just a side note: You would not have run into this had you not mixed up concerns and packed everything in a single function. Here we have 2 concerns: 1. filtering a list, given a predicate and 2. the predicate itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `@`-patterns for that:

```
withJob :: [(String, String, String)] -> String -> [(String, String, String)]
withJob [] _   = []
withJob (t@(_,_,x):xs) job
   | job == x  = t : withJob xs job
   | otherwise =     withJob xs job
```

Comment: So `@` helps you have a reference both to the original representation and to the extended one. That's extra handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To expand what @Ingo was getting at: It would be more idiomatic Haskell to write:

```
jobField :: (String, String, String) -> String
jobField (_, _, j) = j

withJob :: [(String, String, String)] -> String -> [(String, String, String)]
withJob xs job = filter (\x -> jobField x == job) xs
```

We might go further:

```
data Person = Person { pName :: String, pAge :: Int, pJob :: String }

filterbyJob :: String -> [Person] -> [Person]
filterbyJob job xs = filter (\p -> pJob p == job) xs
```

And even then:

```
filterbyJob :: String -> [Person] -> [Person]
filterbyJob job = filter (\p -> pJob p == job)
```

Or even:

```
filterbyJob :: String -> [Person] -> [Person]
filterbyJob job = filter ((== job) . pJob)
```

At this point, unless one is going to use `filterByJob` an awful lot, it probably provides no real value beyond just writing the `filter ((== job) . pJob)` where you need it!

The point of this exercise is that there is a powerful function `filter` that one can just make use of, rather than rewriting that pattern of code each time. Not only does it save you time and code, but by reusing a known function, you make the code easier to understand by future programmers (including your future self!)